# Power APPS- Disabling button in the gallery

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I need to disable a button inside a gallery.

Trying these two expressions, both giving error.

Thoughts please! Thank you.

I tried:

```
If(Value(TextInput7_2.Text) > Value(TextInput7.Text), DisplayMode.Disabled, Edit)
```

and

```
If(ThisItem.Cost_mitigation_1 > ThisItem.effect_mitigation_1, DisplayMode.Disabled, Edit)
```

Comment: What is the error message? Are these text inputs added inside the gallery? If data type of  your columns in "Number", try using formula like: `If(ThisItem.Cost_mitigation_1 > ThisItem.effect_mitigation_1, DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)`. Also, make sure you are using correct names of your columns. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Ganesh, did not work. This is the error I have: 

Invalid argument type: expecting one of the following: number, decimal...

Comment: What is the column/data type of `Cost_mitigation_1` and `effect_mitigation_1`? If *not* number, try using: `If(Value(ThisItem.Cost_mitigation_1) > Value(ThisItem.effect_mitigation_1), DisplayMode.Disabled, DisplayMode.Edit)`.

Comment: brilliant! last expression worked nicely! 
Thanks a mill for your support! as always!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the column/data type of `Cost_mitigation_1` and `effect_mitigation_1` *not*  "Number", try using formula in Power Apps like this:

```
If(
   Value(ThisItem.Cost_mitigation_1) > Value(ThisItem.effect_mitigation_1),
   DisplayMode.Disabled,
   DisplayMode.Edit
)
```

`Value` function will return the numeric data type for string inputs.